# Is there a way to extrapolate a 12 month total fee into a monthly fee across multiple clients with different start dates?

Tags: powerbi, dax

This is my first post on this, so please excuse me if I don't go into enough detail, but I'll try my best.

My problem is as per the title, I want to extrapolate fee data from one of my tables across the 12 month period that the contract is active.

I have one column in the "Merged - Service Period" table that represents a total fee that we expect to receive over 12 months. This fee sits under an individual record/row, that also has data such as the name associated with the contract and the start and end date of the contract.

I want to create another table that extrapolates this fee over the next twelve months i.e. if a start date is within the month of Jan, I want to have a column for each month of the year that has the monthly fee (the total fee divided by 12) in each month, and then zero for any other month before the start date and after the 12 months. However, often the customer renews their contract, so in that same row, if a new fee is arranged, I want the updated expected fee.

For clarification, this table has a many to one relationship with a client table where we store client data, which is connected via a client ID if that helps.

I need the client ID's to be the first column, and then the dates to be the following columns (i.e. 202201, 202202, 202203, etc.)

My current attempt at doing this was through a date table and the Service Period table.

Here is an example of all of the important details in the Service Period table:

| serviceperiodID | OwnerID | OwnerName | Statecodename | Startdate | Enddate | Serviceperiodname | HouseholdID | totalfee | totalfee x gst | Current Stage Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AD123-15GAT-OPSSS | C20R2-991MN-LOP92 | Chris R | Inactive | 25/02/2023 | 24/02/2024 | Smith, Sam - 25/2/2023 to 24/2/2024 | LOIF7-JGN25-453JG | $1,100 | $1,000.00 | Service Period Inactive |
| HSB94-875JG-6G8GD | C20R2-991MN-LOP92 | Chris R | Active | 25/02/2024 | 25/02/2025 | Smith, Sam - 25/2/2024 to 24/2/2025 | LOIF7-JGN25-453JG | $2,200 | $2,000.00 | Service Period Active |
| HG049-Y78JF-LAK25 | C20R2-991MN-LOP93 | Chris R | Active | 14/06/2023 | 13/06/2024 | Spears, Britney - 14/6/2023 to 13/6/2024 | JJK83-IOP0S-MG674 | $3,300 | $3,000.00 | Service Period Active |
| NAUS5-JS94B-VT6R7 | C20R2-991MN-LOP94 | Chris R | Inactive | 20/04/2022 | 19/04/2023 | Spears, Britney - 20/4/2022 to 19/4/2023 | JJK83-IOP0S-MG674 | $2,200 | $2,000.00 | Service Period Inactive |
| BHY24-HGF24-JGN51 | C20R2-991MN-LOP95 | Chris R | Inactive | 5/01/2023 | 4/01/2024 | Swift, Taylor - 5/1/2023 to 4/1/2024 | NNBS2-GJS6T-578TF | $5,500 | $5,000.00 | Service Period Inactive |

This is my attempt at making this table. Not sure if I am coming at this from the right angle, but would love some guidance/help.

```
  ExtrapolatedTable = 
  ADDCOLUMNS (
     CROSSJOIN (
        VALUES ( 'Merged - Service Period'[finpal_householdid] ),
        VALUES ( 'Date Table'[YearMonth] )
     ),
     "MonthlyFee", 
     IF (
        CALCULATE (
           COUNTROWS ( 'Service Periods' ),
        ),
        DIVIDE ( RELATED ( **'Merged - Service Period'[Fees Exc. GST]** ), 12 ),
        IF (
           AND (
              'Date Table'[YearMonth] >= 'Merged - Service Period'**[StartMonthYear]**,
              'Date Table'[YearMonth] < DATEADD ( 'Merged - Service Period'[StartMonthYear], 12, MONTH )
           ),
           DIVIDE ( RELATED ( **'Merged - Service Period'[Fees Exc. GST]** ), 12 ),
           0
        )
     )
  )
```

I am getting errors showing up where I have bolded the DAX code above

Anything that has "YearMonth" is currently in the 'YYYY-MM' format. And "householdid" is a string containing letters and numbers.

I am expecting to get an output something along the lines of the following:

| HouseholdID | 202201 | 202202 | 202203 | 202204 | 202205 | 202206 | 202207 | 202208 | 202209 | 202210 | 202211 | 202212 | 202301 | 202302 | 202303 | 202304 | 202305 | 202306 | 202307 | 202308 | 202309 | 202310 | 202311 | 202312 | 202401 | 202402 | 202403 | 202404 | 202405 | 202406 | 202407 | 202408 | 202409 | 202410 | 202411 | 202412 | 202501 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LOIF7-JGN25-453JG | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 83.33333 | 83.33333 | 83.33333 | 83.33333 | 83.33333 | 83.33333 | 83.33333 | 83.33333 | 83.33333 | 83.33333 | 83.33333 | 83.33333 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 |
| JJK83-IOP0S-MG674 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 | 166.6667 | 0 | 0 | 250 | 250 | 250 | 250 | 250 | 250 | 250 | 250 | 250 | 250 | 250 | 250 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| NNBS2-GJS6T-578TF | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 416.6667 | 416.6667 | 416.6667 | 416.6667 | 416.6667 | 416.6667 | 416.6667 | 416.6667 | 416.6667 | 416.6667 | 416.6667 | 416.6667 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Maybe it would be a better approach to do this in a matrix? But I am not sure how I would achieve this.

Comment: Update your question above to include a sample table (with a few rows) in [markdown format](https://tabletomarkdown.com/), together with what the expected result table should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a Measure instead of a Calculated Table.

Create a new Measure similar to:

```
Monthly Fee = 
  SUMX(
    DISTINCT('Merged - Service Period'[finpal_householdid]),
    (
      var minD = MIN('Date Table'[Date])
      var maxD = MAX('Date Table'[Date])
      var top1 = 
        CALCULATETABLE(TOPN(1,
          FILTER(
            'Merged - Service Period',
            [Startdate] <= maxD && [Enddate] >= minD
          ),
          [Startdate], DESC
        ))
      var fee = CALCULATE(MAX('Merged - Service Period'[Fees Exc. GST]), top1)
      var result = DIVIDE(fee, 12)

      return COALESCE(result, 0)
    )
  )
```

Then use a Matrix visual with:

- Rows: `'Merged - Service Period'[finpal_householdid]`
- Columns: `'Date Table'[YearMonth]`
- Values: `[Monthly Fee]`

Note: You will get a `Can't display the visual` error, this will go once the measure is added to the Values.

[image]

---

**Supplemental**
The above assumes there isn't a relationship between `Date Table` and `Merged - Service Period` tables. If you do have a relationship, then either remove it, or, use the following version of the measure:

```
Monthly Fee = 
  SUMX(
    CALCULATETABLE(
      DISTINCT('Merged - Service Period'[finpal_householdid]),
      REMOVEFILTERS('Date Table')
    ),
    (
      var minD = MIN('Date Table'[Date])
      var maxD = MAX('Date Table'[Date])
      var top1 = 
        CALCULATETABLE(TOPN(1,
          FILTER(
            'Merged - Service Period',
            [Startdate] <= maxD && [Enddate] >= minD
          ),
          [Startdate], DESC
        ), REMOVEFILTERS('Date Table'))
      var fee = CALCULATE(MAX('Merged - Service Period'[Fees Exc. GST]), top1)
      var result = DIVIDE(fee, 12)

      return COALESCE(result, 0)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sam!

It is very close to working, but for some reason when I use the measure, it only fills out the monthly fee on the start date, but nothing else around it. Do you know why this could possibly be the case?

Comment: Most likely you have a relationship between the two tables. See Supplemental section at the bottom of the updated answer.